# How can I install mod_dav_svn 1.6 on CentOS 5.4?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, svn, mod-dav-svn

I'm trying to install `mod_dav_svn` on CentOS 5.4, and this is what I see:

```
# yum --enablerepo=rpmforge install mod_dav_svn
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirrors.adams.net
 * base: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * extras: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * rpmforge: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * updates: mirror.steadfast.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod_dav_svn.x86_64 0:1.4.2-4.el5_3.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: subversion = 1.4.2-4.el5_3.1 for package: mod_dav_svn
--> Running transaction check
---> Package subversion.i386 0:1.4.2-4.el5_3.1 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
[...]
```

Version 1.4.2 is older than my installed Subversion 1.6.9 (I installed it before). How and where can I get `mod_dav_svn` in version 1.6.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also a script provided from WANdisco for the latest pristine open source binaries.  This will setup a repository and you can "yum update" to the latest anytime:

http://wandisco.com/subversion/os/downloads

Comment: +1 Both WANdisco and CollabNet have paid developers who support Subversion initiatives.  Going this route can be beneficial if you ever have the need for paid support.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up yum priorities? RPMForge has subversion and mod_dav_svn 1.6.13, so they should be listed in installations and updates. Yum priorities will hide them if another higher priority repo has the same package names.

If so, you will need to add exclude patterns to your /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo file, by adding to the [base] section:

```
[base]
...
exclude=subversion*,mod_dav_svn
```

Comment: Actually, it seems rpmforge has removed subversion for some reason. I'll post another answer as I also provide that version which I had been mirroring as I don't like rpmforge.

Answer (score 0):

It seems rpmforge has removed its subversion packages for some reason. I provide the same packages (unchanged, other than signing with the webtatic pgp key) in my Webtatic repository. See about setting up the repo here:

http://www.webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/

then you should be able to install mod_dav_svn. It will also upgrade subversion to 1.6.13 in the process.

```
yum install mod_dav_svn --enablerepo=webtatic
```